# How to compute $\int _\mathbb{R}\frac{sin^{2n}t}{t^{2n}}dt$?

Tags: fourier-analysis, improper-integrals

If $n=1$ we can compute $\int _\mathbb{R} \frac{sin^{2}t}{t^{2}}dt$ by using Parseval's formula since $\widehat{1_{[-1,1]}}(x)=2\frac{\sin x}{x}$. We obtain $\int _\mathbb{R} \frac{sin^{2}t}{t^{2}}dt=\pi$. Is there a similar way in order to compute $\int _\mathbb{R}\frac{sin^{2n}t}{t^{2n}}dt$ ?

It seems to be difficult to compute $\int 1_{[-1,1]}\ast \ldots \ast 1_{[-1,1]}(x)^2dx$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the integrand is even, your integral is $2\int_0^\infty\dots dt$. For this 
[MathWorld (38)](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SincFunction.html) gives a closed form in terms of [Eulerian numbers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerianNumber.html)
$$\int_0^\infty \left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)^{2n} \mathrm{d} x = \frac{\pi}{2(2n-1)!} 
\genfrac{<}{>}{0}{}{2n-1}{n-1}$$