# Solve $\int_{0}^{\infty}\ln\Big(\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2}+1\Big)dx=?$

Tags: convergence-divergence, improper-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

I can't calculate the following integral

> $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\ln\Big(\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2}+1\Big)dx=?$$

I can prove that it converges because:

$$\forall x\geq 0\quad  \ln(x+1)\leq x$$

So :
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\ln\Big(\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2}+1\Big)dx<\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2}dx=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

Logically proceeding from my bound, I tried using power series without any success. See [Wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=power%20series%20ln%28sin%28x%29%C2%B2%2Fx%C2%B2%2B1%29) for more details. I think that [integration by parts](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integration%20by%20parts%20ln%28sin%28x%29%C2%B2%2Fx%C2%B2%2B1%29) can give something interesting, but I cannot go further with that. I think it's not a hard integral but I cannot solve it.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance for all your contributions.

Comment: which textbook or resource is this problem from? is there an answer key? if so whats the final answer?

Comment: @Sid Maybe hard to believe but it's basically what you get when playing with function and integral of Dirichlet.Unfortunately I have not the result.Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Note that $$\ln(1+t) = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1} \frac{t^n}{n}$$
so \begin{align*} I &= \int_0^\infty \ln \left( \frac{\sin^2 x}{x^2} +1 \right) dx \\
& =  \int_0^\infty \sum_{n = 1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1} \frac{1}{n}\frac{\sin^{2n} x}{x^{2n}}dx 
= \sum_{n = 1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1} \frac{1}{n}\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin^{2n} x}{x^{2n}}dx
\end{align*}
One can refer [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/307510/a-sine-integral-int-0-infty-left-frac-sin-x-x-rightn-mathrmdx?noredirect=1&lq=1) to have \begin{align*} \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin^{2n}x}{x^{2n}}dx &= 
\frac{\pi}{2^{2n} (2n-1)!} \sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^k {2n \choose k} (2n-2k)^{2n-1} \\
& = \frac{n \pi  }{ (2n)!} \sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^k {2n \choose k} (n-k)^{2n-1}
\end{align*}
So 
\begin{align*} I & = \pi \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{ (2n)!} \sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^k {2n \choose k} (n-k)^{2n-1}
\end{align*}

I cannot simplify this more. When I can do I will edit this post.

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but note that if you expand the binomial coefficient the $(2n)!$ terms will cancel.

Comment: Yes it is. Though $(2n-k)!$ term is annoying one can cancel the term

Comment: A simplified expression for the $\operatorname{sinc}^{2n}(x)$ integrals in terms of Eulerian numbers can be found in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1238747/348034)